# How to add text to d3.js force directed circles?

Tags: d3.js

I'm working on a force directed graph and have been successful in displaying circles connected by links. However, when trying to append text to the nodes, I am having trouble.

I have tried changing things so the circle and text are contained in a single node, but then the force functions no longer work and the circles show up overlapped in the upper left-hand corner of the container.

This is what I have right now (I'm building inside of a `react` component).

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import '../../custom_styles/bpForceDirected.css';

interface IProps {
    data?: string;
    linkData?: string;
}

/* Component */
export const MyD3Component = (props: IProps) => {

    const d3Container = useRef(null);

    useEffect(
        () => {
            if (props.data && d3Container.current) {
                var w=500;
                var h=500;
                const svg = d3.select(d3Container.current)
                            .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + w + " " + h )
                            .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet");

                var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
                    .nodes(props.data);
                simulation
                    .force("charge_force", d3.forceManyBody())
                    .force("center_force", d3.forceCenter(w / 2, h / 2));

                //draw circles for the nodes and adding text
                var node = svg.append("g")
                        .attr("class", "nodes")
                        .selectAll("circle")
                        .data(props.data)
                        .enter()
                        .append("circle")
                        .attr("r", 10)
                        .attr("fill", circleColor);

                node.append("text")
                    .attr("dx", 12)
                    .attr("dy", ".35em")
                    .text(function(d) { return d.id });

                function tickActions() {

                    node
                        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
                        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

                    link
                        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
                }  

                  simulation.on("tick", tickActions );

                var link_force =  d3.forceLink(props.linkData)
                    .id(function(d) { return d.id; })

                simulation.force("links",link_force)

                var link = svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "links")
                    .selectAll("line")
                    .data(props.linkData)
                    .enter().append("line")
                        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                        .style("stroke", linkColor);
            }
        },

        [props.data, d3Container.current])

    return (
        <svg
            className="d3-component"
            ref={d3Container}
        />
    );
}

export default MyD3Component;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot append a **text** element to a **circle**.
First, create a **g** for each node:

```
var node = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "nodes")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(props.data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
```

Then, append a **circle** and a **text** to each **g**:

```
node.append('circle').attr('r', ...)
node.append('text').text(...)
...
```

Replace

```
node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
```

with:

```
node.attr('transform', d => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`);
```

Comment: When I make the change, I see in the markup generated that the circle and text are in a single node, but now the `force simulation` has no impact on the nodes. The nodes are showing overlapped in the upper left-hand corner of the container. Any ideas? It looks like my `tickActions` function should still be updating the positions.

Comment: Updated answer works! There's some overlap with the text going from one node going over others, but I'm sure that can be helped by added drag capabilities to the nodes. What exactly is the difference between the original and replacement `node.attr` piece? Sorry, I'm new to `D3`, so I'm still trying to wrap my head around it all.

Comment: 'cx' and 'cy' are attributes of <circle>, but they don't work with <g>. The coordinates and scale of <g> can be changed with the 'transform' attribute